# Using nullptr to call function

Tags: c++, nullptr

Sorry I couldn't think of any better title after I encountered the following piece of code while experimenting.

What I don't understand here is how could I call a function of the class using a nullptr in this case.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class test {
   public:
      void testfunc() {
         cout << "calling test func" << endl;
      }
};

int main () {
   unique_ptr<test> ptr;
   if (ptr == nullptr) {
      cout << "ptr is null" << endl;
   }

   ptr->testfunc();
   return 0;
}
```

According to me this should just crash because its a nullptr, but it doesn't and work like as if ptr is not a nullptr.

Comment: It's bad luck, nothing more. Undefined behavior means that anything can happen, including running as if there was nothing wrong.

Comment: Here's what [GCC](http://goo.gl/N5o0oV) can do to it.

Comment: It doesn't use the this ptr, it's the same as test * ptr=0;
   ptr->testfunc(); undefined but most compilers are OK with it.